# snowsql - tls_process_server_certificate

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, python-3.6

New to snowsql.

Installed snowsql and ran the command `snowsql -a <account_name> -u <user_name>` and that failed
with below error:

> 2022-04-28 18:50:59,058 (21492/MainThread)
> snowflake.connector.vendored.urllib3.connectionpool WARNING
> connectionpool:781  - Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None,
> read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by
> '***SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines',
> 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify
> failed')],)",),)':***
> /session/v1/login-request?request_id=#####&request_guid=#####
> 2022-04-28 18:50:59,059 (21492/MainThread)
> snowflake.connector.vendored.urllib3.connectionpool DEBUG
> connectionpool:975  - Starting new HTTPS connection (2):
> <account_name>.snowflakecomputing.com:443 2022-04-28 18:50:59,227
> (21492/MainThread) snowflake.connector.network DEBUG
> network:1034 - Hit non-retryable SSL error,
> HTTPSConnectionPool(host='<account_name>.snowflakecomputing.com',
> port=443): Max retries exceeded with url:
> /session/v1/login-request?request_id=0b8e3a19-e618-4554-93a9-eb3a8c6d3a11&request_guid=97351d12-de91-422b-aecc-2fe38bef3032
> (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines',
> 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify
> failed')],)",),))

even tried running

```
snowsql -a <account_name> -u <user_name> -o insecure_mode=True
```

the result was the same.

Not sure if i need to make any change to `SYSTEM$WHITELIST`.

the `snowcd` after installing worked just fine.

Comment: As you suspected, you probably need to make changes based on `SYSTEM$WHITELIST`. One probable reason for this is a packet inspector on the network (Palo Alto, Cisco, Zscalar). Running SnowCD can help: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowcd.html

Comment: thank you for response Greg. I did and snowcd passed all checks with whitelist from Snowflake. yet the problem persists.

Comment: If you ran SnowCD on the same machine, that should rule out network and local machine security. I'd open a case with Snowflake Support on this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SSL certificate error is due to an SSL proxy that intercepts the SSL/TLS certificate by decrypting the certificate, inspecting and re-encrypting the certificate. Some SSL proxies insert an extra certificate into the SSL chain.

This action renders the certificate chain invalid, as Snowflake doesn't support an SSL proxy that decrypts our certificate and replaces the certificate. SSL-TLS Interception (AKA TLS Proxy or HTTPS Interception) is by definition a Man-In-The-Middle attack. Therefore, this is a risk to Snowflake and it will not be supported.

Please refer to the document here:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowsql-start.html

Snowflake's security model does not allow Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) proxies (using an HTTPS certificate). Your proxy server must use a publicly-available Certificate Authority (CA), reducing potential security risks such as a MITM (Man In The Middle) attack through a compromised proxy.

If you must use your SSL proxy, we strongly recommend that you update the server policy to pass through the Snowflake certificate such that no certificate is altered in the middle of communications.

To use Snowsql insecure mode, you will need to edit the Snowsql config file by adding the following to the [option] section:

```
insecure_mode = True
```

The configuration file can be found in either one of these locations:

```
 /etc/snowsql.cnf
 /etc/snowflake/snowsql.cnf
 /usr/local/etc/snowsql.cnf
 <HOME_DIR>/.snowsql.cnf (supported only for backward compatibility)
 <HOME_DIR>/.snowsql/config
```

Please refer to the Snowsql config guide here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowsql-config.html